# HttpRequestException Content Length mismatch with form data

Tags: c#, salesforce

I'm writing a .NET web application that sends data to Salesforce Omnichannel Inventory. The payload is "multipart/form-content."

I created a web form to fill out by end users. When they post the form, the form model is translated into a string that matches the newline-delimited JSON formatting that is required by Omnichannel Inventory.

File structure is this:

```
{"location": "ABC","mode": "UPDATE"}
{"recordId": "88948e62-5267-456d-82b3-cfb886dd7780","onHand":"12345","sku":"1111","effectiveDate":"2023-07-24T11:01-24.526-04:00"}
```

Step that generates authorization tokens (not sure if needed to help troubleshoot since it is Salesforce Core Platform):

```
public async Task<string> GenerateCoreAuthTokenAsync(string environment)
{

    var endpoints = _endpointSettings.Get(environment);
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoints.AuthorizationUrl);
    var collection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    collection.Add(new("grant_type", "password"));
    collection.Add(new("client_id", endpoints.ClientId));
    collection.Add(new("client_secret", endpoints.ClientSecret));
    collection.Add(new("username", endpoints.Username));
    collection.Add(new("password", endpoints.Password + endpoints.SecurityToken));
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(collection);
    request.Content = content;
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(responseContent);

    var authToken = (string)obj["access_token"];

    return authToken;
}
```

Step that saves the written string to a JSON file and returns the file name for later use:

```
public async Task<String> GenerateInputPayload(CustomInputModel input)
{
    Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    var warehouseString = "{\"location\": \"ABC\",\"mode\": \"UPDATE\"}";
    StringBuilder payloadString = new StringBuilder();
    payloadString.Insert(0, warehouseString);
    payloadString.Insert(warehouseString.Length, "\n");
    payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, "{\"recordId\": \"");

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(guid.ToString()))
    {
        payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, guid);
    }

    payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, "\",\"onHand\":\"");

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input.OnHand))
    {
        payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, input.OnHand);
    }

    payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, "\",\"sku\":\"");

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input.ProductId))
    {
        payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, input.ProductId);
    }

    payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, "\",\"effectiveDate\":\"");

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input.EffectiveDate))
    {
        payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, input.EffectiveDate);
    }
    else
    {
        payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm'-'ss.fffK"));
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input.ExpectedDate) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(input.FutureOnHand))
    {
        string normalizedExpectedDate = "";
        string[] formats = { "MM/dd/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy",
                        "MM/dd/yy", "M/dd/yy", "M/d/yy", "MM/d/yy",
                        "MM-dd-yyyy", "M-dd-yyyy", "M-d-yyyy", "MM-d-yyyy",
                        "MM-dd-yy", "M-dd-yy", "M-d-yy", "MM-d-yy"};
        DateTime tempAddedOnStartDate;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(input.ExpectedDate, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                               out tempAddedOnStartDate);
        normalizedExpectedDate = tempAddedOnStartDate.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm'-'ss.fffK");
        payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, "\",\"futures\": [{\"quantity\": \"");
        payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, input.FutureOnHand);
        payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, "\",\"expectedDate\": \"");
        payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, normalizedExpectedDate);
        payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, "\"}]}");
    }
    else
    {
        payloadString.Insert(payloadString.Length, "\"}");
    }

    var fileName = "inventory" + guid + ".json";
    fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(AppContext.BaseDirectory), fileName);
    FileStream fs = null;
    try
    {
        fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.Write(payloadString);
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fs != null)
            fs.Dispose();
    }

    return fileName.ToString();
}
```

Step that finds the inventory file created, sends the payload. This results in a Content-Length mismatch, where I send less data than is expected:

```
var authorizationToken = await GenerateCoreAuthTokenAsync(environment);
var fileName = await GenerateInputPayload(input);

var endpoints = _endpointSettings.Get(environment);

var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoints.InstanceUrl +  "/services/data/" + endpoints.ApiVersion + "/commerce/oci/availability-records/uploads");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authorizationToken);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StreamContent(System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName)), "fileUpload", "inventory.json");
request.Content = content;
var dump = new StreamReader(request.Content.ReadAsStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

I've tried comparing this to successful Postman requests, but I don't see any discernable difference. The Postman request translates to this in C#:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://[url].sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v57.0/commerce/oci/availability-records/uploads");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer [token]");
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "BrowserId=[string]; CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:1");
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("[location of file]")), "fileUpload", "[name of file]");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Anyone know why I am not sending the same amount of data defined in the Content-Length header when I send the request?